# Lemma of asymptotics in chapter 4, PDE by Evans

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics

The lemma is from chapter 4.5 in PDE by Evans, I don't really understand the proof and have questions about it.

> **Lemma**(Asymptotics). Suppose that $k,l:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions, that $l$ grows **at most** linearly and that $k$ grows **at least** quadratically. Assume also there exists a unique point $y_0\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $$ k(y_0)=\min_{y\in\mathbb{R}}k(y).$$ Then $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} l(y)e^{\frac{-k(y)}{\epsilon}}dy}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-k(y)}{\epsilon}}dy}=l(y_0).$$
> **Proof**. Write $k_0=k(y_0)$. Then the function $$\mu_\epsilon(y):=\frac{e^{\frac{k_0-k(y)}{\epsilon}}}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{k_0-k(z)}{\epsilon}}dz}\quad\quad (y\in\mathbb{R})$$ satisfies $$\mu_\epsilon\geq 0,\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mu_\epsilon(y)dy=1,$$
> $$\mu_\epsilon\to 0 \text{  exponentially fast for } y\neq y_0,\text{ as }\epsilon\to 0.$$
> Consequently, $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} l(y)e^{\frac{-k(y)}{\epsilon}}dy}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-k(y)}{\epsilon}}dy}=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}l(y)\mu_\epsilon(y)dy=l(y_0).$$

Now I am wondering:

1. How to estimate the decay speed of $\mu_\epsilon$ as $\epsilon\to 0$ or more generally, the decay speed of integral in this form $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{(k_0-k(y))/\epsilon}.$$
2. Why "**consequently**" we get the desired result. In my opinion, we should try to prove that $\mu_\epsilon$ is a good kernel, i.e. it's positive, its integral is 1, and for every $R>0$, $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{|y|>R}\mu_\epsilon(y)dy=0$.

Can anyone help me with my problems? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer (1). For question 2, the positivity and the fact that the integral is 1 follows from the positivity of the exponential the definition you wrote down and the fact that the in the definition is finite: since $k$ grows at least quadratically, there exists a positive constant $C$ and some real number $D$ such that
$$k(y) \geq k_0 + D + C(y-y_0)^2.$$

(Use a compactness argument if you want to make this rigorous.)

Note that this means
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(k_0 - k(z))/\epsilon}dz \leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-D -C(z-y_0)^2/\epsilon}dz < \infty.$$
Appropriately, this gives us positivity and the integral of $\mu_\epsilon$ being 1:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mu_\epsilon(y)dy := 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{(k_0 - k(y))/\epsilon}}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(k_0 - k(z))/\epsilon}dz }dy  = 1.$$

Now, we aim to prove the exponential decay statement that Evan gives, where we could use the quadratic growth of $k$ along with [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method), but we will use the following coarse bound instead.

Fix $y \neq y_0$. Take $\epsilon > 0$. Then by the inequality we gave above,
\begin{align*} 
\mu_{\epsilon}(y) &= \frac{e^{(k_0 - k(y))/\epsilon}}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(k_0 - k(z))/\epsilon}dz}
\\
&\leq 
\frac{e^{(k_0 - k(y))/\epsilon}}{\int_{y_0 - \delta}^{y_0 + \delta} e^{(k_0 - k(z))/\epsilon}dz}
\\
&= 
\frac{1}{\int_{y_0 - \delta}^{y_0 + \delta} e^{(k(y) - k(z))/\epsilon}dz}
\end{align*}

Since $y_0$ is the unique minimum of $k$, $k$ is continuous, and $y \neq y_0$, we can pick $\delta$ small enough such that for all $z$ such that $|z - y_0| < \delta$,
$$k(z) \leq (k(y) - k(y_0))/2 = \eta > 0.$$
This $\eta$ will depend on $y$ and $\delta$, but for our purposes this doesn't matter. We end up with
$$\mu_\epsilon(y) \leq \frac{1}{\int_{y_0 - \delta}^{y_0 + \delta} e^{\eta/\epsilon}dz}$$

which exhibits the exponential decay that Evan's said it had. In particular, we have shown that outside of a neighborhood $(y_0-\delta, y_0 + \delta)$ of $y_0$,
$$\mu_\epsilon(y) \leq \frac{e^{-\eta/\epsilon}}{2\delta}.$$

From this point, it isn't hard to show that $\mu_\epsilon$ satisfies the properties of a good kernel using a proof similar to what I did above (after fixing $R > 0$, make $\eta = \min_{|x| \geq R} \frac{k(x) - k(y_0)}{2}.$)